# Determine the equation of the function of 4th degree

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

The question is the following

> Polynomial function of 4th degree crosses the $x$-axis at $x=1$ and $x=-1$. It also has a minimum at $(0,-1/2)$. Determine the function.

So I know that the function has to look like this: $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$.
I am given the points $(-1,0)$, $(1,0)$ and I can also use the first derivative and equal it to $0$, since there is a minimum there. I still can't figure out the solution. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems to me that you don't have enough information, unless you know that this function has no other zeros, and no other local extrema.

Comment: You seem to be missing what the information you are given MEANS!  Yes, you are "given the points (-1, 0) and (1, 0) which means that (x+ 1) and (x- 1) are factors so [math]f(x)= (x+ 1)(x- 1)(ax^2+ bx+ c)[/math].    f(0)= (0+ 1)(0- 1)(c)= -c= -1/2 so c= 1/2.

Comment: You seem to be missing what the information you are given MEANS!  Yes, you are "given the points (-1, 0) and (1, 0) which means that (x+ 1) and (x- 1) are factors so [math]f(x)= (x+ 1)(x- 1)(ax^2+ bx+ c)[/math].    f(0)= (0+ 1)(0- 1)(c)= -c= -1/2 so c= 1/2.  f'(x)= (x- 1)(ax^2+ bx+ 1/2)- (x+ 1)(ax^2+ bx+ 1/2)+ (x+1)(x- 1)(2x+ b) so that f'(0)= -1/2- 1/2- b)= 0 so b= -1.  That means that f(x)= (x+ 1)(x- 1)(ax^2- x+ 1/2).  But we do not have enough information to determine a

Answer (score 2):

From the fact it is 4th degree and has roots $1,-1$ we know that the function can be written as

$f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(ax^2+bx+c)$

From that it has value of $f(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ we can learn then that $c$ in the above is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, so we know it is of the form

$f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(ax^2+bx+\frac{1}{2}) = (x^2-1)(ax^2+bx+\frac{1}{2})=ax^4+bx^3+\frac{1}{2}x^2-ax^2-bx-\frac{1}{2}$

We then can use that $f(0)$ is a minimum, noting that $f'(0)=0$ to learn that $b=0$ since $f'(x) = 4ax^3+3bx^2+x-2ax-b$ and so $f'(0)=-b=0$

Lastly, since this is a minimum and not a maximum, we can learn something about the range of values that $a$ can take, though we can not pinpoint what exactly $a$ is.  For $0$ to have been a minimum of the graph, that implies that $f''(0)$ would need to be positive implying that $1-2a>0$ and so $a<\frac{1}{2}$

Final answer:

$$f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(ax^2+\frac{1}{2})~~~\text{with }a<\frac{1}{2}$$

or written expanded out as

$$f(x)=ax^4-ax^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}~~~\text{with }a<\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Providing comments when downvoting is considered the polite thing to do.  If the downvote was in reference to the amount of work the OP showed, I am of the opinion that they showed enough.  If the downvote was in reference to the content of my answer because something was unclear or incorrect, then kindly ask for clarification so I can elaborate or explain it better.

Comment: Perhaps one might have interpreted the phrase "has a minimum" not to mean "has a (local) minimum" but rather "has a global minimum" at that point.  Due to the nature of 4th degree polynomials, we could further specify the value of $a$ to be positive in that interpretation, though I would not have read the question that way myself.